# How to delete all temp files using powershell

Tags: powershell, temporary-files, temp

Anyone knows how to delete all temp files using powershell.

`Get-ChildItem $env:TEMP\TEMP | Remove-Item -confirm:$false -force -Recurse`

I tired this code but it couldn't work.
Can you suggest me any better way to perform the same.

Comment: Are you trying to delete a `TEMP` folder inside the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` folder?

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to see any errors, you could use the -ErrorAction switch like this:

```
Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP\* -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: warning! this command will delete the `Temp` folder itself so you will not have `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp` exists after command is executed. You can try to use `$env:temp\*` to delete the `Temp` folder content only.

Comment: Most of the times it's nice to only delete files older than some days -- e.g. `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path $env:TEMP | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)} | rm -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` and then delete empty directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637537/1011025

Answer (score 4):

To empty TEMP folder **and leave the folder in place**, you should use this command:

```
Remove-Item $env:TEMP\* -Recurse
```

If you don't want to type so much, you can use also shorter version:

```
rm $env:TEMP\* -r
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Recurse -Force
```

Of course you will get access errors if any of the files you are deleting are actually being used by the system.

Answer (score -2):

I'm running PS as LOCAdmin and run following command

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>$tempfolders = @(“C:\Windows\Temp\*”, “C:\Windows\Prefetch\*”, “C:\Documents and Settings\*\Local Settings\temp\*”, “C:\Users\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*”)
PS C:\Windows\system32>Remove-Item $tempfolders -force -recurse
```

works for me :)

Comment: Downvoted for plagiarising from https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-clean-out-temp-folders/  You should follow the guidelines on referencing other sources at https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing