# How do I remove a Folder in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

we got a small script that creates folders named by the daily date. I got a script that deletes folders which are older than 30 days.

```
dir "\\nas\Backup_old\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Where { ((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30} |
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Principally it works fine. The Subfolders with contend will be deleted.
But the main folder is still existing and the LastWriteTime is canged to the runtime of the script. The folder is empty. Someone have a idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you can look fol emty folders en delete folders look here hihttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631419/how-to-recursively-remove-all-empty-folders-in-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to remove the second instance of `Get-ChildItem` (noting that `dir` is just an alias for `Get-ChildItem`), as that is causing it to remove the children of each of the directories returned by the first:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\nas\Backup_old\*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { ((Get-Date) - $_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30} |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Have a look at the WhatIf output and if it looks like it will now remove what you expect, remove `-WhatIf`.